# Taylor series of a function $f(x,y)$ about point $(a,b)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative, plane-geometry

The general expression for Taylor series is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables).

My book says we can write the Taylor series about origin $(0,0)$ as:

$f(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{2} [f_{xx}\ x^2 + 2f_{xy}\ xy + f_{yy}\ y^2]$

*because the linear terms vanish because of the position of the axes.*

Is this perfectly correct about $(0,0)$ or is it an approximation?

Comment: Yes...............

Comment: Do you calculate a Taylor serie of a specific function or you are talking about a general function? The constant and linear coefficients don't generally vanish.

Comment: general function $f(x,y)$